# Break jquery alert into two lines

Tags: jquery, alert, line-breaks

I have this query alert which works just fine to alert the two columns of data, however the data is combined like this:

**January31**

and I want it to display

**January

31**

$("#month").on("click", "tr", function showText(event){
            alert($(this).text());

Answer (score 0):

You can add new lines to text by using `"\r\n"`. You'll have to add that between the Month and Day value in your text field.

Wherever you're displaying the text, you need to add the `"\r\n"`, as the text value is what you'd need to insert into. I can't help without unless you actually provide that code.

```js
alert("This is a multi-line \r\ncomment");
```